# Menu item active when it shouldn't be

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

If this question has been answered elsewhere, I apologize, but I'm curious as to why on my site: goo.gl/2OCsyb the menu item "news" is selected when just "tattoos" should be. Same goes when you click though to an artist's "post" page: goo.gl/A7NS6g "News" again is selected, but now "tattoos" is not selected at all. Has anyone dealt with this issue? If so, anything helps. Thanks!

Here's the list code:

```
<div class="menu-header">

<ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu sf-js-enabled">

<li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40">

<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-menu-item menu-item-41 active">

<li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-42">

<li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60">

<li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-121 selected active">
<a href="http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/news/">News</a>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59">
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: remove class active on you news section li tag

Comment: include your css pls..

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is two

```
current_page_parent
```

and

```
selected active
```

class in menu link.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one USER----- seems to be a small mistake**

I just visited your website [Tattos Archive](http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/category/tattoos/).. Gud work...

```
Change the "Selected active" from your code line

<li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-121 selected active">
```

and replace it with

```
<li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-121">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is tattoos parent catagory for news ? i am not sure about this anyways try this

```
    #navigation ul li.active a{
       color: #d9a13b;
   }
```

instead of this apply the style only to this

```
   current-menu-item{
       color: #d9a13b;
   }
```